# convert from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have problem with converting this peace of code.  I try to use converters but no luck at all. All converters has problem with this part "view.Filter = delegate(object item)"
Thanks in advance.

```
    private void ApplyFilters()
    {
        // Get the view
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);
        if (view != null)
        {
            // Create a filter
            view.Filter = delegate(object item)
            {
                // Show the current object
                bool show = true;

                // Loop filters
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> filter in columnFilters)
                {
                    object property = GetPropertyValue(item, filter.Key);
                    if (property != null)
                    {
                        // Check if the current column contains a filter
                        bool containsFilter = false;
                        if (IsFilteringCaseSensitive)
                            containsFilter = property.ToString().Contains(filter.Value);
                        else
                            containsFilter = property.ToString().ToLower().Contains(filter.Value.ToLower());

                        // Do the necessary things if the filter is not correct
                        if (!containsFilter)
                        {
                            show = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Return if it's visible or not
                return show;
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? SO is not a language translation service. It's a programming related Q&A site so please use it as such. Also please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) to convert the [C# anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx):

```
view.Filter = Function(item As Object)
        ' Show the current object
        Dim show As Boolean = True

        ' Loop filters
        For Each filter As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In columnFilters
            Dim prop As Object = GetPropertyValue(item, filter.Key)
            If prop IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Check if the current column contains a filter
                Dim containsFilter As Boolean = False
                If IsFilteringCaseSensitive Then
                    containsFilter = prop.ToString().Contains(filter.Value)
                Else
                    containsFilter = prop.ToString().ToLower().Contains(filter.Value.ToLower())
                End If

                ' Do the necessary things if the filter is not correct
                If Not containsFilter Then
                    show = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next

        ' Return if it's visible or not
        Return show
      End Function
```

Comment: I already try this solution but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's because VB.Net doesn't support anonymous methods.

You could try extracting the delegate code into a separate function call and then run it through a converter.

Comment: Thanks for your respond but I try already. Does not work.